# How to get user access token from Facebook API with curl

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I am writing a program that retrieves our marketing data from facebook. the program i am writing can only use curl to retrieve the user access token and there is no UI, the only info I found is to call this url

```
Curl('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=1534273216862757&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html','GET')
```

However, when I send this, i get back the entire html of the redirect page and no token.

do you know of another way I can accomplish this?

thanks

Comment: did you call curl on the command line and add `-v` ? This will tell you which cookies and headers are passed. Which language do you use to call the Curl() function ? PHP ? -> Please add the proper tag to your question

Answer (score 3):

You can only get a User Token with user interaction, not by curl. It does not work like that, and it should not work like that.

You can use an Extended User Token though, it is valid for 60 days. After that, the user has to refresh it.

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: ok, so is there any way to query the data from graph api? i was able to retrieve app token with curl

Comment: curl for an app token? you can just generate an app token with "app-id|app-secret", you don´t need any curl call for that. user tokens can´t just generated without user interaction. they are USER tokens, so there has to be a real user authorizing the app and requesting the token.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I need to build a program that retrieves data for a data warehouse. it's an automated program, no user is involved, so do I have to have the user access token or is there another way to retrieve campaigns data?

Comment: if you need a user token for it (and i guess you do), then there is no way

Comment: What if you need to auth with facebook for unit tests?

Comment: it may be possible to use test users for that, check out the docs for those

Comment: @andyrandy How do I programatically get page token for creating posts?

Comment: there is no way to get a token programmatically - unless you have a valid user token already? that one needs user interaction though.

Answer (score -2):

There is some information:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Your access_token can be as: `{your-app_id}|{your-app_secret}`. Attention: it's application token, not user token. It's limited, therefore you can't make such requests as `/me`.

Or try this request to get access-token:

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={app_id}&client_secret={app_secret}&grant_type=client_credentials&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}`

The {redirect_uri} is any route of your application, and this uri must be in "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" in this page: `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{app_id}/fb-login/settings/`

I don't check this solution because I need request some permissions (manage_pages, leads_retrieval). I'm waiting for it will be granted.